# auto resize cell heights

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak

hello i start learning obj-c and want to increase call log cells after write this code i have many issues with cell heights
i want to have same default cell heights for all cells

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <UIKit/UITableViewController.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface MPRecentsTableViewCell
@property (readwrite, strong, nonatomic) UITableView * tableView;
@property (readwrite, assign, nonatomic) long long tableViewDisplayMode;
@property (readwrite, strong, nonatomic) UISegmentedControl * tableViewDisplayModeSegmentedControl;
@property (readwrite, assign, nonatomic) bool tableViewNeedsReload;
@end


%hook MPRecentsTableViewController
//-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)arg1 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)arg2 {
    return 200;
  }
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 60.5;
}

%end
```

result:-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuHWZ.jpg)

many size no one work

Comment: Are you designing cells in Storyboard or through code? If code, show us your cell class code. If you're using Storyboard Prototype cells, show us how you've configured the constraints.

Comment: @DonMag I’m writing. This code and this is the whole code

Answer (score 0):

To enable dynamic cell height with Auto Layout constraints in Swift, you need to set up your cell with constraints that define its size based on the content. Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

or in swift

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
```

Comment: Do not implement `heightForRowAtIndexPath` if you return the same value for all rows. Simply set the `rowHeight` property of the table view to that one value.

Comment: Another way 

Set automaticDimention in viewDidLoad - 

        tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44